# Get different partition numbers via dataframe.rdd and rdd

Tags: apache-spark

I have three json files that are placed under the directory: `d:/applog/output/1703658001908`.

Then, I read the json files with the following code. As you can see, the number of partitions from `spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)` is 3, and `spark.read.json(path).rdd` is 1.

I have no idea why the result is different, I look through the code of `JsonDataSourceV2`, looks that there is no optimization that will merge the files automatically.

```scala
val path = "file:///d:/applog/output/1703658001908"
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkTest 0005").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile(path)
assert(rdd.getNumPartitions == 3)

val df = spark.read.json(path)
assert(df.rdd.getNumPartitions == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Spark SQL has the optimzation while reading file, the three files are small, so that,spark sql collect them into one partition.